# Two CSS style sheets change input tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to incorporate bootstrap-tags into my website. I have downloaded source code from Github [bootstrap-tags](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) and it comes with its own CSS style sheets. On my current website I have a stylesheet that adds attributes to the HTML `<input>` tag. The CSS that came with the Github source code also adds attributes to the HTML `<input>` tag and these two conflicting styles return unexpected results.

So there are two style sheets

```
main.css
bootstrap-tags.css
```

I have three inputs

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name (Required)">
</div><!-- /.col -->
</div><!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email (Required)">
</div><!-- /.col -->
</div><!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="subjects" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput">
</div><!-- /.col -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

I want the first two `<input>` tags to be affected by `main.css` and the last `<input>` tag to be affected by the `bootstrap-tags.css`. How can I achieve this?

I know I can add classes to the inputs and not add CSS to the `<input>` tag directly but I want to keep my direct CSS to the `<input>` tag.

Comment: You can't tell elements to be affected by one stylesheet and not another.

Comment: Is it possible to make one class more important than another? For example `class="class1 class2 !important"` and then class2 would have higher priority?

Answer (score 0):

**How I solved the problem**

This technically is not an answer because it does not solve the actual question.

From what I have been told and what I have researched an element can't decide what style sheet it receives its attributes from. Therefore I was forced to create a CSS class and gave every attribute `!important` tag to override the CSS for the `<input>` tag.